# silverlight C# code

Tags: silverlight-4.0

This is coded in Service.svc.cs file

```
 [OperationContract]
            public List<Branch> GetAllBranch()
            {

                List<Branch> Br = new List<Branch>();
                using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
                {
                    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = "GetBranch";
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        con.Open();
                        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                        while (dr.Read())
                        {
                            Branch BrName = new Branch();
                            BrName.Name = Convert.ToString(dr["BranchName"]);
                            Br.Add(BrName);
                        }
                        dr.Close();
                    }
                }
                return Br;
            }

            public class Branch
            {
                public string Name { get; set; }
            }
```

End of Service file Code----

This is coded in the Form

```
 ServiceClient client= new ServiceClient();
                test.GetAllBranchCompleted += (s, ea) =>
                    {
                        cboBranch.ItemsSource = ea.Result;
                    };
                client.GetAllBranchAsync();
```

My requirement is I want to populate all the Names of the Branches that are present in my database.With this code the combobox for BranchName is getting populated but not with the Database records but something like this CRUD.ServiceReference1.ServiceBranch.
CRUD is my solution Name.

Please correct me with this..
Thanks

Comment: You don't say what `cboBranch` is, but you need to create a template for the display of items of type `Branch`. This is usually done in XAML.

Comment: cboBranch is my  ComboBox in which im looking to populate the Names of Branches from my Database...
Cant i do it this way without doing it in XAML...I have done it in DatagridView and its working fine with the same code.I just wanna populate it in ComboBox.

DGV.ItemsSource = ea.Result;
This is the line that i have replaced when im using DataGrid.
DataGridView is the name of my DGV

Answer (score 1):

To get just the name to appear in your ComboBox you need to result a `List<string>`. Here you are returning a `List<Branch>`.

So you either need to rework your service code or just extract a list of strings from your `ea.Result`.

```
cboBranch.ItemsSource = ea.Result.Select(b => b.Name).ToList();
```

*(from memory)*